# how to do add two values to same key in and object

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am practising a hackerrank question on Jade template and expressjs.
The files are as follows.
**app.js**

```
// set 'jade' as the 'view engine'
// render the jade template engine with the following data as parameter:
// option:"teachers" / "students",
// Students:["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
// Teachers :["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE"]
// run the application on port 8000

const express= require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set("view engine","jade")

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    
   res.render('index', {
    option:'students' || 'teachers',
   Students:["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
   Teachers :["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE"]
  });
})

app.listen(8000)
```

**index.jade**

```
html
  title Jade Template Engine
  body
    h1 Conditions and Loops in Jade
    if option==="students"
      ol
        each name in Students
          li #{name}
    else if (option === "teachers" )
      ol
        each name in Teachers
          li #{name}
    else
      p You have entered wrong option!
```

How do I sent either **"students"** or **"teachers"** but not both as parameter to **option** variable from **app.js** to **index.jade**

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```js
const express= require('express');
var app = express();
        
app.set("view engine","jade");
app.set("views","./views/")
        
app.get('/:option', (req,res) => {
    Alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
    Beta = ["f", "g", "h", "i"];
        
    var check = (req.params.option === 'alpha') ? true : (req.params.option === 'beta') ? true : false;
          
    res.render('view', {
        options: req.params.option,
        hasParams:check,
        itemList: (req.params.option === 'alpha') ? Alpha: (req.params.option === 'beta') ? Beta : ''
    })
});
        
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('view', {hasParams: false})
});
        
app.listen(8080);
```

```jade
doctype html
html
    head
        title Page
    body
        if hasParams
            ol 
                each item in itemList 
                    li #{item}
        else 
            p You have entered wrong option!
```

Comment: 1.used render()
2.condition for Alpha/Beta
3.condition for /root

Answer (score 0):

This will work use
for **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "jade")

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

res.render('view', {
option: "teachers",
Students:["Athul", "Ramij", "Nil", "Satyaki", "Souvik"],
Teachers :["Swarnali", "Paromita", "Poulomi", "sreejukta"]
});

})

app.listen(8080);
```

This for **view.jade**

```
html
title "Jade Template Engine"
body
h1 "Conditions and Loops in Jade"
 if (option === "students")
   ol
    each name in Students
      li #{name}
 else if (option === "teachers" )
  ol
    each name in Teachers
      li #{name}
else
  p "You have entered wrong option!"
```

you have to give space before if statement aligns the else with if .test case will pass or just copy above code it will work